# WPF ComboBox in Popup does not get keyboard focus when a pdf in WebBrowser has keyboard focus

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, combobox, webbrowser-control

Is there a keyboard focus problem in WPF? I created a little test project with only one WebBrowser control and 1 editable ComboBox within a PopUp as well as a TextBox. I set source of the WebBrowser to a pdf document. When the keyboard focus is within the pdf and I click on the ComboBox I am not able to enter text into it. When the keyboard focus was in the TextBox before I clicked on the ComboBox, it's possible to enter text into it.

```
    <TextBox/>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="247" Margin="496,133,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
               </WebBrowser>
    <Popup IsOpen="True">
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="282,150,0,0" IsEditable="True" PreviewMouseDown="ComboBox_PreviewMouseDown" />
    </Popup>
```

And to set the pdf:

```
  webBrowser1.Source = new Uri(@"c:\temp\a.pdf");
```

What is the right way to make it possible to edit the popup's ComboBox when coming from the pdf in WebBrower control?

Comment: I think this the behavior, that the `WebBrowser` control introduces. There is no simple quick fix for this issue. This control wraps MFC or native Win32 code to embed all sorts of content. So you have to handle it on Win32 level by intercepting Windows events (message loop). You will find more in the web. Look for "WebBrowser steals focus" or something like that.

Comment: If it's only about displaying PDF files, why do you want to embed it? Just start a process using `Process`. The OS will handle it and opens the file automatically with the default PDF viewer (e.g. Browser like Edge). Just call `Process.Start(@"c:\temp\a.pdf");`. This way you can use the additional features of the external readers too.

Comment: I don't want to start the pdf in a separate windows. That's way I use the WebBrowser control.

Comment: My current solution is to intercept the mouse click, set the focus to a control outside the popup and back to the combobox. It's not perfect, but it words acceptable.